# How to switch pages in the Xamarin Shell without a back button?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, xamarin.forms.shell

I want to make a home button at the top of the Shell-based APP.
(Referring to the Xanimals app.)

The purpose of this home button is to move to one of the specific Routined pages in the Shell.

The gotoasync() function adds the previous page to the navigation stack by default, and the Backward button is enabled.
I don't want the back button, I just want to move like when you press the flyout button in Shell structure.

Please help me.

Comment: what will be the function of " home button" the same as back button? or you just want to disable back button?

Comment: What I want to do is to switch to a specific page when I press the Home button. There should be a menu button instead of a back button.

Comment: try with `Shell.Current.Navigation.PopToRootAsync()` instead of `GotoAsync()`

Comment: hmm.. Is there any way to get to a specific page without saving the previous page history?

Comment: Do you try  to use `Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync()` method ?

Comment: It doesn't work.  added an explanation because I thought the question was ambiguous.

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the  current page or  add a new page into the shell FlyoutItem after you click the home button ?

Comment: i meant replace( or switch )the current page(like 3rd figure above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below method :

in your home button click event:

```
Shell.Current.CurrentItem.CurrentItem.Items.Add(Your new Page);
Shell.Current.CurrentItem.CurrentItem.Items.RemoveAt(0);
```

Comment: It works as intended. thx for your answer. But this is the same result as the method previously tried.
Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
The method you gave me is to replace the newly created page with a new page().

I need the same function that goes to the previously created page(not new page()) when I press the button on the flyout menu.

Comment: Because of the design it seems impossible to achieve this effect completely.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this method which switches to a different navigation stack; assuming the home view is registered with a route name of `home` in your AppShell.xaml

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//home");
```

Here's a reference to all route formats:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#absolute-routes